# Repetition of same score on different team

Tags: database, neo4j, cypher, data-modeling

[image]I am new in Neo4j and have faced a problem while displaying the top five teams that have the best scoring power using neo4j on the following data set.Problem is each teams are taking the same highest score i.e 6.Help me Please

Below has some part of data.

```
Round,Date,Team 1,FT,HT,Team 2

1,(Fri) 11 Aug 2017 (32),Arsenal FC,4-3,2-2,Leicester City FC

1,(Sat) 12 Aug 2017 (32),Brighton & Hove Albion FC,0-2,0-0,Manchester City FC

1,(Sat) 12 Aug 2017 (32),Chelsea FC,2-3,0-3,Burnley FC

1,(Sat) 12 Aug 2017 (32),Crystal Palace FC,0-3,0-2,Huddersfield Town AFC

1,(Sat) 12 Aug 2017 (32),Everton FC,1-0,1-0,Stoke City FC

1,(Sat) 12 Aug 2017 (32),Southampton FC,0-0,0-0,Swansea City AFC

1,(Sat) 12 Aug 2017 (32),Watford FC,3-3,2-1,Liverpool FC

1,(Sat) 12 Aug 2017 (32),West Bromwich Albion FC,1-0,1-0,AFC Bournemouth

1,(Sun) 13 Aug 2017 (32),Manchester United FC,4-0,1-0,West Ham United FC

1,(Sun) 13 Aug 2017 (32),Newcastle United FC,0-2,0-0,Tottenham Hotspur FC

2,(Sat) 19 Aug 2017 (33),AFC Bournemouth,0-2,0-0,Watford FC

2,(Sat) 19 Aug 2017 (33),Burnley FC,0-1,0-0,West Bromwich Albion FC
```

> I have find out top five team "team 2" which has greater score than
>   team 1 and display result by splitting the column data into array and
>   compare `Score Ft[0] < Score Ft[2]`.Then five different teams with same
>   score appears .

```
  t2.key s

 "Southampton FC" 6

 "West Bromwich Albion FC" 6

 "Watford FC" 6

 "Brighton & Hove Albion FC" 6

 "Crystal Palace FC" 6
```

Comment: Do you have this data in neo4j? 
This query doesn't make any sense. 
You are trying to match random nodes from neo4j database(Not from the file you are using this query) and then checking two scores from the file. 
I suggest you separate the data loading and calculation.

Comment: Load the data first into Neo4j and then run the query.

Comment: Yes.The data is in the neo4j and I am trying to match the nodes on the basis of greater score on FT.But the main problem here I am getting is nodes are taking the same value instead of taking different one.Could you please help me on coding view.

Comment: Sure, Can you show me the data model? Where are you storing these scores in the database? (I mean as a property of a relationship or any node)?

Comment: You can use this tool to create the model. http://www.apcjones.com/arrows/#

Comment: You can also share the screenshot of neo4j browser, where I can see how the nodes are cretaed and what are the properties of each, node/relationship?

Comment: Post is edited by putting image on the top section of question.

Comment: Where are the scores stored? I can see you stored the scores in EPL nodes but these are not connected to the Team nodes! we can not relate in the Cypher query if these are not connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you try a data model like this, it's clear from this model like MATCH, Teams involved in this match and date of the match etc.

You can also move the properties score from the relationships PLAYED to node MATCH.

This just a suggestion you can improve this according to your use case.

[image]

Comment: Note also that if you want to make it very fast to get a teams wins and losses, you might consider adding a second relationship, either :WON or :LOST as appropriate, to the match in question (this is in addition to the :PLAYED relationship). That way, you can use `size((team)-[:WON]->())` (or the :LOST equivalent) to get the number of wins or losses from the relationship degree data on the node itself without actually having to expand the relationship to the other side, and this is more performant. If you like, you can even get rid of the :PLAYED relationship completely and use :WON and :LOST.

Comment: Yeah, Replacing PLAYED by WON and LOST will be more performant and easy to query. I shared this model to start with and then improve as per the use case.